# R combinations of column vectors with names of new vectors as combination of original vectors

Tags: r

Apologies for the embarrassingly simple problem. I want to create combinations of all column vectors in a data frame, add the new vectors and rename them as a combination of the original column vector names.

For example

```
  A B V3 V4 V5 V6
1 1 3  1  3  3  9
2 2 4  4  8  8 16
3 3 5  9 15 15 25
```

I'd like V3 to be named A*A, V4 to be A*B, V5 to be B*A...etc

the closest I have come is a python solution via a 'for loop'. Makes sense, but what is the r syntax to name the columns?

```
df<-data.frame(x1=1:3,x2=3:5)
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(df){
    df[i,"-",j]<-df([,i]*df[,j])
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I could use sapply instead of a loop but I am still stuck with renaming the new columns:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=1:3,x2=3:5)
a[3:6]<-sapply(a[1:2],"*",a[1:2])
```

Many thanks,
LR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `expand.grid`

```
d1 <- expand.grid(names(df), names(df))
df[do.call(paste0, d1)] <- apply(d1, 1, FUN = function(x) do.call(`*`, df[x]))
df
#  x1 x2 x1x1 x2x1 x1x2 x2x2
#1  1  3    1    3    3    9
#2  2  4    4    8    8   16
#3  3  5    9   15   15   25
```

---

Or another option is

```
do.call(polym, c(df, degree = 2, raw = TRUE))
```

Or

```
poly(as.matrix(df), degree = 2, raw = TRUE)
```